# How many votes did Scalise receive for speaker in the full House?

Tags: united-states, congress, speaker

I can find information about how much he earned against Jordan in the Republican-only vote but amazingly not about how much he earned in a straight vote in the full house. I've only read that it's significantly under 217.

Answer (score 2):

Scalise withdrew his bid after the closed-door party vote, and so no floor vote was taken. The party vote was secret, so we don't know the exact tallies, but I expect he performed about as well as Jordan: enough votes to secure a strong majority, but not enough to get the 217 needed in the full House.

Answer (score 0):

He got 7 votes and I have included the entire vote breakdown.

- Jeffries: 212
- Jordan: 200
- Scalise: 7
- McCarthy: 6
- Zeldin: 3
- Garcia, Mike: 1
- Emmer: 1
- Cole: 1
- Massie: 1
- Present: 0
- Not Voting: 1

Comment: Yes, the vote for when Jordan was nominated is available. That's actually what prompted me to ask the question, to see how his success compared to Scalise when he was nominated. I meant the first time Scalise came up, before he dropped out (those votes for Scalise are no doubt messaging votes).

Comment: @user84614 I am not sure what else can be told as there is no way to determine why people voted for him.